# Visual Studio 2005 SQL report project-- can't find my custom assembly

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2005, report

I have a SQL Server report project in VS 2005 that won't preview one of my reports.  This report uses a custom assembly with some code we wrote.  I've set a reference to this assembly in the Report Properties menu, but whenever I try previewing the report, I get a message that says in part, "Could not load file or assembly ((my assembly)) or one of its dependencies.  The system cannot find the file specified."

I'm not sure how else to point the report project to my assembly, or if as the message says, it's a dependency of my assembly that's the problem, how to identify that dependency.

I have other reports in this project that don't use the custom assembly, and they run just fine in preview mode.  Also, the assembly I'm using is being used by my coworkers in their VS 2005 report projects with no trouble.  So I think it's some setting on my box that's at issue.

If you have any suggestions I'm happy to hear them, and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what got me over the hump.  It turns out VS 2005 has its own directory locations it looks at for assemblies and config files, separate from SSRS.  This post describes it well:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1010780.aspx/1?SQL+Server+Reporting+Services+2005+Custom+Assembly+Error

The bit about 'rspreviewpolicy.config' is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the custom assembly dll has been deployed correctly.  If you run from your local, the dll should be copied to

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQLServer\80\Tools\Report Designer

folder on your computer.

If you run report from server, then it should be in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL\Reporting
>   Services\ReportServer\bin

in the server. (please note, if your server have multiple SSRS instances running, the directory might be a little different based on your server configuration.)

Comment: Thanks.  I found another link that helped me on this too-- I'll post it below.